# Basic examples of InfoGrid applications

Tags: graph, nosql, datastore

I am trying to use this software called [InfoGrid](http://infogrid.org/) for a project that I am building. Can someone please point me to some basic getting started articles. I don't see any documentation on the site.

*Peopl with enough reputations, please edit the question and add the tag **InfoGrid** to this question.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I joined the infogrid mailing list and wrote to the dev team to include a simple getting started article. The dev's have been kind enough to provide the same on their wiki here: http://infogrid.org/wiki/Examples/FirstStep

Answer (score 1):

I am an early user and have some experience I can share. Basically this stuff rocks. It's quite hard to get your head into at first but once once you get past the "aha" it makes complete sense.